# Hanging Indent For Unordered List Items In Paragraph

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to indent the second+ line of text in an unordered list that resides within paragraph text so that all rows are even. However, when I insert the styles below, it messes with the main nav.

```
ul {
    list-style: disc outside none; 
    margin-left: 0; 
    padding-left: 1em;
}
li {
    padding-left: 1em;
}
```

I've also tried p.ul and p ul as well, but no luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: Show us your HTML. We haven't a crystal ball

Comment: Parapgraphs should not contain lists - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191327/nest-lists-in-paragraphs-in-html

Comment: `code`<h3>Requirements:</h3>
<ul>
 <li>3 months in business</li>
 <li>$5k minimum monthly credit card sales OR $15k minimum monthly revenue</li>
 <li>Must deposit at least 10 times per month</li>
</ul>`code`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a CSS selector that only goes after nested list elements.

i.e.

```
ul > ul { Will select first nested ul }
ul ul { Will select all nested ul's NOT including the parent ul }
```

Or in your case -

```
p > ul { }
```

That may work, but without seeing your markup its hard to be exactly accurate.

Another option - add class names to make it easier for CSS to select specific elements

i.e.

```
<p class="info-block">
   <ul>
       <li>Some list Item</li>
   </ul>
</p>
```

CSS

```
.info-block ul { padding-left: 1em; }
```

But as Paulie_D said - ***Paragraphs should not contain lists***
[Nest lists in paragraphs in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191327/nest-lists-in-paragraphs-in-html)

Instead I would suggest using a `<div>`

Comment: Switched to using a div and this solution worked. Thank you very much!