# Wrapping <ol> lists into <p> tag

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

I need to wrap all `<ol>` lists into `<p></p>` tags.
I tried do it so

```
text = text.replace(/(<ol>.*<\/ol>)/g, '<p>$1</p>');
```

But it not works. If I have input text like

```
 <ol>   <li>item1</li>  <li>item2</li>  <li>item3</li> </ol>
```

after `text.replace` the text remains the same.

As I found out, the cause of the problem is in multi-line.
I have maked simple test.

```
var list = '<ol>'+   
'<li>item1</li>'+   
'<li>item2</li>'+   
'<li>item3</li>'+  
'</ol>';
list = list.replace(/(<ol>[\s\S].*[\s\S]<\/ol>)/g, '<p>$1</p>');
alert(list);
```

and I get in result

```
<p><ol><li>item1</li><li>item2</li><li>item3</li></ol></p>
```

But if I modify the test so

```
var list = '<ol>\n'+   
'<li>item1</li>\n'+   
'<li>item2</li>\n'+   
'<li>item3</li>\n'+  
'</ol>';
list = list.replace(/(<ol>[\s\S].*[\s\S]<\/ol>)/g, '<p>$1</p>');
alert(list);
```

so I get

```
<ol>
<li>item1</li>
<li>item2</li>
<li>item3</li>
</ol>
```

**Edit:**
No, it is not duplicate question with [Nest lists in paragraphs in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191327/nest-lists-in-paragraphs-in-html)
I need to wrap lists in a form input, not in html.

Comment: Are you trying to replace the ol or the li?

Comment: @Pete-iCalculator — They said they were trying to *wrap* the `ol` with the `p`. So no. They aren't replacing anything.

Comment: Yes, I trying to wrap the `ol` with the `p`.